# Enzyme button simulate doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following react-native test code.

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';

import {
  BorderlessButton,
  InputBox,
  ProgressBar,
} from 'components';

import Name from '../name.component';

describe('Name component', () => {
  let wrapper: any;

  const mockOnPress = jest.fn();
  const mockSaveStep = jest.fn();

  const mockProps: any = {
    errors: null,
    values: [{ givenName: 'givenName', familyName: 'familyName' }],
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Name signUpForm={mockProps} saveStep={mockSaveStep} />);
  });

  it('should render Name component', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should render 2 <InputBox />', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(InputBox)).toHaveLength(2);
  });

  it('should render a <ProgressBar />', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(ProgressBar)).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('should render a <BorderlessButton /> with the text NEXT', () => {
    expect(wrapper.find(BorderlessButton)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(BorderlessButton).props().text).toEqual('NEXT');
  });

  it('should press the NEXT button', () => {
    wrapper.find(BorderlessButton).simulate('click');
    expect(mockOnPress).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But the last test doesn't work properly. How can I simulate a this button click? This gives me an error saying

> expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled().
>   Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

This is the component.

```
class NameComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { saveStep } = this.props;
    saveStep(1, 'Name');
  }

  disableButton = () => {
    const {
      signUpForm: {
        errors, values,
      },
    } = this.props;

    if (errors && values && errors.givenName && errors.familyName) {
      if (errors.givenName.length > 0 || values.givenName === '') return true;
      if (errors.familyName.length > 0 || values.familyName === '') return true;
    }
  }

  handleNext = () => {
    navigationService.navigate('PreferredName');
  }

  resetForm = () => {
    const { resetForm } = this.props;
    resetForm(SIGN_UP_FORM);
    navigationService.navigate('LoginMain');
  }

  render() {
    const { name, required } = ValidationTypes;
    const { step } = this.props;

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{ flex: 1 }}
          behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null}
          enabled>
          <ScreenContainer
            navType={ScreenContainer.Types.LEVEL_THREE}
            levelThreeOnPress={this.resetForm}>

            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <SinglifeText
                  type={SinglifeText.Types.H1}
                  label='Let’s start with your legal name'
                  style={styles.textLabel}
                />

                <View style={styles.names}>
                  <InputBox
                    name='givenName'
                    form={SIGN_UP_FORM}
                    maxLength={22}
                    placeholder='Given name'
                    containerStyle={styles.givenNameContainer}
                    inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                    errorStyles={styles.inputError}
                    keyboardType={KeyBoardTypes.default}
                    validations={[required, name]}
                  />
                  <InputBox
                    name='familyName'
                    form={SIGN_UP_FORM}
                    maxLength={22}
                    placeholder='Family name'
                    inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainer}
                    errorStyles={styles.inputError}
                    keyboardType={KeyBoardTypes.default}
                    validations={[required, name]}
                  />
                </View>

                <SinglifeText
                  type={SinglifeText.Types.HINT}
                  label='Please use the same name you use with your bank'
                  style={styles.hint}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </ScreenContainer>

          <ProgressBar presentage={(step / MANUAL_SIGNUP_STEP_COUNT) * 100} />

          <View style={styles.bottomButtonContainer}>
            <BorderlessButton
              text='NEXT'
              disabled={this.disableButton()}
              onPress={this.handleNext}
            />
          </View>

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this??

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work properly' what do you mean? What is the error?

Comment: The way I will test this is that you have to also mock the function that will be triggered when the button is clicked and change to

expect(function).toHaveBeencalled();

Comment: Can you add the whole test code? This will help us to know where the actually problem really is.

Comment: Updated the post with the full test code.

Comment: Whats the actual onclick fucntion are you calling? I guess mockpress is just a mock name. Can you post the component code as well. Just wanted to see which function are you calling on the onclick event.

Comment: Updated with the component code

Comment: I don't see any `onClick` events in the component though.

Comment: I want to write it for BorderLessButton's onPress

Comment: HI Raman, Could you do me a favor? Could you show me how to pass 100% code coverage and tests for this component?? I have to fix this today and im stuck.

Comment: @Shashika, running this code could show you the code coverage `jest --coverage --verbose`

Answer (score 0):

You create the function `mockOnPress()`, but `mockOnPress()` is never injected into the component.

In the component you wrote, `NameComponent` has a child `BorderlessButton` component, in which the line, `onPress={this.handleNext}` is hard-coded in. `handleNext()` is defined elsewhere as:

```
handleNext = () => {
    navigationService.navigate('PreferredName');
}
```

To test that the functionality of the button is working, I see two viable options. One is to use **dependency injection**. Instead of hard-coding the button to call `navigationService.navigate('PreferredName')`, you could have it execute code that is passed in as a prop. See the following as an example:

```
it('Button should handle simulated click', function (done) {
  wrappedButton = mount(<MyButton onClick={() => done()}>Click me!</BaseButton>)
  wrappedButton.find('button').simulate('click')
}
```

Note that you could take the principle provided in the above example and expand it to your example by passing in the functionality you want to occur onClick as a prop to your NameComponent.

Another option you have, is to test whether clicking the button causes the side effects you want to occur. As written, pressing the button should call, `navigationService.navigate('PreferredName')`. Is this the intended effect? If so, you can change your test to validate whether `navigationService.navigate('PreferredName')` was called somehow.